# How to change border radius of legend symbol

Tags: highcharts

I have a area chart. Its legend symbol comes up with a border radius.
Tried the below code and I could remove the the radius in IE9. Does not work in IE7.Please help.

```
$(chart.series).each(function () {
this.legendSymbol.attr({
                    'rx': 0,
                    'ry': 0,
                    'border-radius': '0px',
                    'height': 12
                });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Border-radius is not supported by IE7, unfortunately.

Please check this matrix:
http://caniuse.com/border-radius

Comment: But i can see the legend symbol has a border radius in IE7. I want to remove that.Will that not be possible as well?

Comment: It is not related with CSS, because we use SVG / VML to generate our charts.

Answer (score 0):

attr() is avaiable only in SVG, but IE6/7 use VML, which not allows to use this function.

EDIT:
You can use small workaround which include "fake" series, which correct marker (like square) and linked area serie with symbol.

```
 series: [{
        name: 'first',
        type: 'scatter',
        color: 'blue',
        id: 'other',
        marker: {
            symbol: 'square'
        }
    }, {
        showInLegend: false,
        name: 'first',
        linkedTo: 'other',
        data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
    }]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Drjyz/1/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So how can we change the borer radius then? There must be someway to do it in VML as well.

Comment: My aim is that the legend symbol should not have the border radius. Any method to achieve this is fine.

Comment: Any ideas will be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

THis code worked for me.

```
if (this.legendSymbol != undefined && this.legendSymbol != null) {
                this.legendSymbol.attr({
                    'rx': 0,
                    'ry': 0,
                    'r': 0,
                    'height': symbolWidth 
                });
            }
```

Specifically the 'r':0 made it work in the VML rendering browsers.
Can I rely on this solution?